# How to create Connection Pooling in Cloud Spanner for the Enterprise applications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, connection-pooling, google-cloud-spanner

I'm pretty new to Cloud Spanenr. I had understood hoe to create connection(dbClient) and use to for transactions and executeQuery/mutations other.
But i'm not clear with how to create the ConnectionPooling for Cloud Spanner 
well there is SpannerOptions, Session/SessionPoolOptions. By just creating

```
 SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder().build();
          Spanner spanner = options.getService();
DatabaseClient dbClient = spanner.getDatabaseClient(db);
```

will handle the connectionPooling required for Enterprise applications.

Is there a proper way to create the JDBC/Hibernate style Connection pooling were we take the connection object form Pool and return to pool for reuse again instead of creating connections multiple time.

I had done creating the connection object and create all type transactions with queries and mutations and other process. I'm in level of creating an Centralized library to provice the connection(dbClient) for multiple dao's. Unable to get proper documentation or process to achieve the JDBC/Hibernate style of Connection Pooling class for Cloud Spanner

```
 SpannerOptions options = SpannerOptions.newBuilder().build();
          Spanner spanner = options.getService();
            try {
              DatabaseId db = DatabaseId.of(options.getProjectId(),SpannerInstanceId, SpannerDatabaseId);

              String clientProject = spanner.getOptions().getProjectId();
              if (!db.getInstanceId().getProject().equals(clientProject)) {
                System.err.println(
                    "Invalid project specified. Project in the database id should match"
                        + "the project name set in the environment variable GCLOUD_PROJECT. Expected: "
                        + clientProject);
              }
              DatabaseClient dbClient = spanner.getDatabaseClient(db);
              dbClient
              .readWriteTransaction()
              .run(
                  new TransactionCallable<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void run(TransactionContext transaction) throws Exception {
                        ResultSet resultSet;
```

Currently i'm trying to repeat the same for each Dao mathod when connection is required. I'm looking to create a centralized class for providing this connection form connection pool and return it for the pool for resue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cloud Spanner a long-lived "connection"/"communication channel" with the database is modeled by a "[Session](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions)" and not a [`DatabaseClient`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/DatabaseClient.java) object. The `DatabaseClient` object already implements connection(session) pooling internally in a [`SessionPool`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/SessionPool.java) object which can be configured via [`SessionPoolOptions`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/SessionPoolOptions.java).

If you want to manage your own sessions, instead of giving a `DatabaseClient` object (or a class wrapping it) to each of your DAO objects, you could initialize your own `SessionPool` and give them each a [`Session`](https://github.com/googleapis/java-spanner/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/Session.java) object (or a class wrapping it).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. It will be great help if you can give an example how to use the SessionPool  and providing each a session? I am not getting any example how to get the session from the pool and return session to the pool and committing process as well and when to close the connection to avoid session leak?

Comment: You can use the `getReadWriteSession()` and `getReadSession()` methods on the `SessionPool` to get a `Session` object and call `close()` on it when it is no longer needed. The APIs are documented in the source.

Comment: The client libraries manage session pooling internally as mentioned by @adi -- you simply create one DatabaseClient for your application instance. 

As mentioned you can configure the SessionPoolOptions, 

Using sessions yourself adds a large amount of uncessaery complexity

Comment: Thanks much, I've got some idea about going forward.